# How to use mypy with derived classes and method calls?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm struggling with mypy not understanding that I want to pass a derived class where the code accepts an instance of the base class or any derived class, and calling a method on that passed instance.

My code:

```py
from typing import Type
import abc

class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base):
    def my_method(self):
        print("Derived")

def my_function(b: Type[Base]):
    b.my_method()  # line 14

d = Derived()
my_function(d)  # line 17
```

When I run this, it prints "Derived" (as expected). But mypy is unhappy with it:

> mcve.py:14: error: Too few arguments for "my_method" of "Base"

> mcve.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "my_function" has incompatible type "Derived"; expected "Type[Base]"

I assume that the line 14 error is because mypy doesn't see that the first argument is in front of the method call (the `base.`), which may be because of the error on line 17?

How do I get mypy to understand this code? Or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Type` is used if you want to pass `Base` or a subclass of `Base` as an argument. You intend to pass an *instance* of such a class.

```
def my_function(b: Base):
    b.my_method()
```

The error on line 14 is taking your type hint literally, and thinks you mean to do something like `Base.my_method(x)` rather than `x.my_method()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Base` as the type for `b`:

```
def my_function(b: Base):
    b.my_method()
```

and `mypy` will accept it.