# Why is mypy complaning about direct subclasses of the expected Type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have looked in both Mypy's docs as well as python's docs as well and I still don't quite understand what is wrong here

```py
from typing import NewType
from numbers import Number


def foo(num: Number):
    print(num)

foo(5)

A = NewType("A", str)
B = NewType("B", A)

test_var_1 = A("test")
test_var_2 = B(A("test"))
test_var_3 = B("test")
```

```py
mypytest.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Number"
mypytest.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "B" has incompatible type "str"; expected "A"
```

According to the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562816/how-to-use-mypy-with-derived-classes-and-method-calls) question mypy shouldn't be complaining about `foo`, isn't the whole point of classes like numbers.Number or collections.abc.Sequence among other abstract classes that you cant hint that any subclass of those are acceptable parameter to a function? (Along with serving for user defined subclasses).

Moreover, with regards to the `NewType` "subclassing", python has an example of this right from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype):

```py
from typing import NewType

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)

ProUserId = NewType('ProUserId', UserId)
```

Mypy Version: 0.910

Python Version: 3.9.7

**EDIT:**
[Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#newtypes) suggests that NewType is equivalent to creating an empty subclass but with less runtime overhead, however the same example from above using classes passes with no issues:

```py
class A(str):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass


test_var_1 = A("test")
test_var_2 = B(A("test"))
test_var_3 = B("test")
```

```py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: The line 8 error seems like a mypy issue, but the line 15 error is correct mypy behavior. `B` takes an argument of static type `A`, and `"test"` is not such an argument.

Comment: [Here's a relevant mypy issue.](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186) Python's static typing is still just full of holes.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I see, seems to be and old issue, either way I actually only stumbled on that problem while trying to troubleshoot why the NewType inheritance wasn't working. If you say B takes static argument A, from the docs there is an example that looks like mine, are you just supposed to make a nested call like I did on line 14?

Comment: "Mypy suggests that NewType is equivalent to creating an empty subclass but with less runtime overhead" - even in the "roughly equivalent to" example code in the link, note the presence of `def __init__(self, _x: Base) -> None:`. It's *not* treated like an empty subclass. `NewType('B', A)` is treated like a subclass with a constructor that takes a single argument of type `A`.

Comment: The docs examples never try to call a sub-NewType with an argument statically typed as the base type. If you want to do that, the `B(A("test"))` structure would be the way to go.