# Mypy error when passing subclass for baseclass

Tags: python, class, mypy

```py
from abc import ABC


class A(ABC):
    ...


class B(A):
    ...


def foo(bar: A): ...


foo(B)
```

Mypy error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Type[B]"; expected "A"

Am I doing something wrong or it's just mypy bug?

Comment: What do you want `foo` to accept, _type objects_ that are `A` or its subclassess (e.g. `A`, `B`), or instances of its subclassess (e.g. `B()`)?

Comment: @Brain was trying to pass type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use mypy with derived classes and method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562816/how-to-use-mypy-with-derived-classes-and-method-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` is a type. `bar: A` means an object of type `A` or anything inherited from `A` (in this case `A()` or `B()`).

So either:

```
foo(B())
```

if you want to pass instances of classes, or

```
from typing import Type

def foo(bar: Type[A]): ...

foo(B)
```

if you want to pass classes themselves.

For python 3.9+:

```
def foo(bar: type[A]): ...

foo(B)
```

though mypy might have some issues with that.